# How to fetch specific fields from array using file_get_contents

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I want to fetch player fields:

e.g id,name,tag,plat etc

I have this type of data:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [player] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 179203896
            [game] => bf4
            [plat] => pc
            [name] => HeLLTiMe
            [tag] => DK
            [dateCheck] => 1391437377733
            [dateUpdate] => 1391437377733
            [dateCreate] => 1386696304438
            [lastDay] => 20140117
            [country] => 
            [countryName] => 
            [rank] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [nr] => 73
                    [imgLarge] => bf4/ranks/r73.png
                    [img] => r73
                    [name] => Chief Warrant Officer Five III
                    [needed] => 4920000
                    [next] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [nr] => 74
                            [img] => r74
                            [name] => Chief Warrant Officer Five IV
                            [needed] => 5030000
                            [curr] => 5022060
                            [relNeeded] => 110000
                            [relCurr] => 102060
                            [relProg] => 92.781818181818
                        )

                )

            [score] => 5025100
            [timePlayed] => 862027
            [uId] => 2832659368608119092
            [uName] => HeLLTiMe
            [uGava] => 0b8b00021ebfb32414e5a6051c2c9a40
            [udCreate] => 1328606863000
            [blPlayer] => http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf4/soldier/HeLLTiMe/stats/179203896/pc/
            [blUser] => http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf4/user/HeLLTiMe/
            [editable] => 
            [viewable] => 1
            [adminable] => 
            [linked] => 
        )

    [stats] => stdClass Object
        (
            [reset] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [lastReset] => 0
                    [score] => 0
                    [timePlayed] => 0
                    [timePlayedSinceLastReset] => 0
                    [kills] => 0
                    [deaths] => 0
                    [shotsFired] => 0
                    [shotsHit] => 0
                    [numLosses] => 0
                    [numWins] => 0
                )
```

How can I fetch this data?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$url = "http://api.bf4stats.com/api/playerInfo?plat=pc&name=HeLLTiMe";
$json = file_get_contents($url);

$data = json_decode($json);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get the name you should do this:

```
echo $data->player->name;
```

You need this because you have a `stdClass Object`

You can also change the out to just a array, you have to change this:

```
$data = json_decode($json);
```

to this:

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

When you make this chagne you can get the value by this:

```
echo $data['player']['name'];
```

**Edit**

Below you can see the example, this works for me with no error.

```
$url = "http://api.bf4stats.com/api/playerInfo?plat=pc&name=HeLLTiMe";
$json = file_get_contents($url);

echo 'Using stdClass Object option<br>';
$data = json_decode($json);
echo $data->player->name;

echo '<br><br>Using Array option<br>';
$data = json_decode($json, true);
echo $data['player']['name'];

exit;
```

Comment: echo $data['player']['name']; is returning empty result

Comment: and echo $data->player->name; is generating error : Trying to get property of non-object in E:\test\api.php on line 8

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array();

$result['name'] = $data->Player->name

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: I can also have this url: http://api.bf4stats.com/api/playerInfo?plat=pc&name=HeLLTiMe&output=js
what in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what do you mean by fetch the data as already fetched it but if you ask how to access the fields you can do it like this.

```
print_r($data->player->name);
```

Comment: I just want to access some of the fields, like name, plat etc.

Comment: Also your answer is generating error : Trying to get property of non-object in E:\test\api.php on line 8